# Progress bar onclick button in android?

Tags: android, location

How to bring a progress bar on clicking a button in an activity i have an button in my main activity and if i click the button i want to display a progress bar i dont wanna use a secondary activity for this i have done with 2 activities but i need it to be done in main activity itself.

thank you

My code:

Home Activity :

```
public void load(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Splash.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Splash Activity :

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    private long ms = 0;
    private long splashTime = 20000;
    private boolean splashActive = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread mythread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                        if (!paused)
                            ms = ms + 100;
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        mythread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do like this

```
ProgressDialog progress;

progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Please Wait!!");
progress.setMessage("Wait!!");
progress.setCancelable(true);
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progress.show();
```

call this code where you want to display your `ProgressBar`.

Comment: I am not downvoting you but using progress.setCancelable(false); is really bad idea.

Comment: @Vipul Shah Can you show me how to show this loading screen button click simply.

Comment: @VipulShah It is not a bad idea, but it is not meant to be done always.

Answer (score 6):

There is one more method to show the ProgressBar on Button Click.

Put this code in your xml

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

and just write following code on your Button click in java file.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It will show the Progressbar on your Button Click.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the user2306156 will not be in need of this now, hopefully someone who is looking for this will be glad to know i guess.

put this code in your xml

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
```

put this in your activity code

```
spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this in your onClick of the activity code

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [Android Progress Bar Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/)

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnStartProgress;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
        btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
                 new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            // prepare for a progress bar dialog
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            progressBar.setMessage("In Progress ...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.show();

            //reset progress bar status
            progressBarStatus = 0;

            //reset filesize
            fileSize = 0;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                  // process some tasks
                  progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

                  // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  // Update the progress bar
                  progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                  });
                }

                // ok, file is downloaded,
                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                    // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // close the progress bar dialog
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
              }
               }).start();

               }

                });

        }

    // file download simulator... a really simple
    public int doSomeTasks() {

        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

            fileSize++;

            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                return 30;
            }
            // ...add your own

        }

        return 100;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Option is to use the nifty [Spezi-Views](https://github.com/halfreal/spezi-views), it contains a ProgressButton which is quite easy to use:

```
<de.halfreal.spezi.views.ProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press me"
        app:selectedText="I am loaded"
        app:unselectedText="Press me again"
        app:loadingDrawable="@drawable/spinner"
        />
```

and in code:

```
...
//show a rotation spinner, and no text (or the loading text)
progressButton.enableLoadingState();

//show no animation, but the selected/ unselected text
progressButton.disableLoadingState();
...
```